# Active Directory Replicated Attributes Replication System Flags

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

In Active Directory Schema, attribute entries have a "System-Flags" attribute that indicates some options for attributes including their Replication across domain controllers.

From the remarks section at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx I found out that

1. System-Flags Bit 1 indicates that an attribute will not be replicated.
2. System-Flags Bit 2 indicates that an attribute will be replicated to the "global catalog"

I am a programmer who uses AD as a service provided by the infrastructure team. So I don't even know what "global catalog" is, but I am just looking for all non-replicated attributes so I can query all Domain Controllers for them to find the value I need.

I ran a bitwise query to find all the non-replicated attributes that have Bit 1 ON in its System-Flags. I got a list of attributes.

```
(&(objectCategory=attributeSchema)(systemFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=1))
```

I wanted to test the consistency of this by querying for attributes that are both replicated and not by checking for attributes with bits 1 and 2 both ON.

```
(&(objectCategory=attributeSchema)(&(systemFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=1)(systemFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))
```

I thought this second query for this nonsensical query of replicated-and-not-replicated attributes would return no results, but it did return 14 attributes (including `Object-Guid`). Now I'm wondering whether the infrastructure team made a mistake, or I'm misunderstanding something about how AD (or LDAP in general) works.

Is this an error or do I need to know something?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223141.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(&(objectCategory=attributeSchema)(systemFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=3))
```

Which would indicate both bit 1 and bit 2 are set.

Comment: Thanks but this is semantically identical to my query (&(systemFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=1)(systemFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
Anyways I tried it and the same results: 14 attributes. I am wondering in my question about why there are results when there shouldn't.

Comment: I also got the object-guid.

Comment: i don't see an object-guid in that ldap query

Comment: Mine shows cn: 
Object-Guid
systemFlags: 19
(which is 00010011, which matches search)
I get 14 also.

Comment: Sorry ج, I misunderstood your remark. So you're saying you go a result in which there is the attribute "object-guid" as a replicated + non-replicated property. But the question is how come, object-guid is replicated? Thanks for showing me that i'm not the only person with these results!

Answer (score 0):

A global catalog is a multi-domain catalog that allows for faster searching of objects without the need for a domain name. It helps in locating an object from any domain by using its partial, read-only replica stored in a domain controller. As it uses only partial information and a set of attributes that are most commonly used for searching, the objects from all domains, even in a large forest, can be represented by a single database of a global catalog server.

so your query returns attributes which are in both the Global catalogue partial attribute set and attributes which are not replicated.